# Function to determine "pretty" cuts for an arbitrary sequence

Tags: r, quantile

I want to cut an arbitrary sequence of numbers into intervals using `cut`. The limits should be derived automatically by providing just the *number*  of intervals I want to have in the end.

The interval limits should be "nice" i.e. typically multiple of 1, 2, 2.5, 5 times a power of 10.

Function `pretty` does a decent job of determining "pretty" ticks for an axis.

```r
set.seed(14112023)
x <-runif(200, 0, 100)
pretty(x, 5)
#   0  20  40  60  80 100
```

But by design it uses equidistant cuts:

```r
pretty(c(x, 10000), 5L)
# [1]     0  2000  4000  6000  8000 10000
```

which is totally fine for what it is meant to do (axis ticks) but is less useful for my use case as the intervals become very unevenly filled:

```r
y <- c(x, 10000)
table(cut(y, pretty(y, 5L)))

#     (0,2000] (2000,4000] (4000,6000] (6000,8000] (8000,10000] 
#          200           0           0           0            1
```

I could use `quantile` to get nicely distributed limits, but the values are "ugly":

```r
round(quantile(y, seq(0, 1, length.out = 5)), 2)
#       0%      25%      50%      75%     100% 
#     0.61    32.61    58.47    79.91 10000.00
```

Thus, ideally I am looking for a function which takes a range of values (like the quantiles) and looks for the next "nice" number, e.g.:

```r
pretty_limits(quantile(y, seq(0, 1, length.out = 5)))
# [1] 0 25 50 75 10000

table(cut(y, c(0, 25, 50, 75, 10000)))
#     (0,25]    (25,50]    (50,75] (75,10000] 
#         36         49         56         60
```

Here, I have an even distribution with nice limits. My data will be potentially skewed, so I don't care if the buckets are not perfectly evenly distributed, but I don't want an extreme case where only 2 buckets are filled.

*N.B.*  I am totally aware that "nice" is a rather vague concept, but I can live very well with the definition of `pretty` and want to achieve a similar functionality for cuts rather than equidistant ticks on an axis. Also, the choice of my nice values is subjective, `0 20 40 60 80 10000` would be another valid choice. Any heuristic will be fine as long as the cuts are mutiple of 1, 2, 5 times a power of 10 (just as `pretty` does).

Comment: in `pretty_limits`, why does 32.61 get turned into 25? surely it should be 30? It is good that you acknowledged your definition of nice is vague, but it would be helpful if you gave an idea of what makes one number (or method) nicer than another

Comment: You are right, as said any number would be fine. and at this stage I would go for any solution as long as it is a multiple of 1, 2, 2.5, 5 or 10.  Subjectively, limits such as 25, 50, 100 are "nicer" than 30, 35 or 60. But I am having a tough time giving a rule. Hence, any solution returning pretty numbers as defined by `pretty` would be fine for the time being as long as the cuts are not leading to heavily imbalancedd cuts..